# Service provider list can not see

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

[image: empty service provider list]

Though i successfully added service providers, it is not listed down in the UI. When i add same one again it gives message like already exist. What is wrong here with me.

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use?

Comment: version : 5.12.0-m14-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an already reported bug for IS-5.12.0-m13 and 5.12.0-m14-SNAPSHOT https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/11498.

You will be able to view the service providers using the console app (`https://localhost:9443/console`)

NOTE: This issue is not in 5.12.0-m12 - https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.12.0-m12